# Associate SH scripts to Windows bash

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-10-v1607, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How can I associate all `.sh` files to new BASH included in Windows 10 Anniversary update?

I have tried associating `.sh` file using default system prompt to `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe` but it just flashes console window with no result.

Comment: It may be that the program is running and then the console window is disappearing when it's run. Try running the .sh files from the console.

Comment: I'd like to point out [WSL Script](https://sop.github.io/wslscript/) application i made for the purpose. It lets you register a filetype that can then be launched from the explorer. Drag & Drop of file arguments to the associated filetype is also supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that BASH uses Unix-like paths and Windows gives DOS paths. So you need to redirect DOS path to Unix path.

**My solution**

It is more like hack than a real solution. **USE AT YOUR OWN RISK**

Write tiny C# console app to redirect paths

```
string[] splt = args[0].Split(':');
string exe = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + "\\bash.exe";
string arguments = "/mnt/" + splt[0].ToLower() + splt[1].Replace('\\', '/');

using (Process process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo.FileName = exe;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;

    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();

    return process.ExitCode;
}
```

And then you associate `.sh` files with this C# app

Dirty but works

Answer (score 6):

It's also possible to do with just a batch file:

```
@echo off

REM Get the full qualified path for the first argument
SET fullpath=%~f1

REM Get the drive letter and convert it to lowercase
SET drive=%fullpath:~0,1%
FOR %%i IN ("A=a" "B=b" "C=c" "D=d" "E=e" "F=f" "G=g" "H=h" "I=i" "J=j" "K=k" "L=l" "M=m" "N=n" "O=o" "P=p" "Q=q" "R=r" "S=s" "T=t" "U=u" "V=v" "W=w" "X=x" "Y=y" "Z=z") DO CALL SET drive=%%drive:%%~i%%

REM Replace \ with /
SET relpath=%fullpath:~3%
SET relpath=%relpath:\=/%

C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe --login "/mnt/%drive%/%relpath%"
```

Now just use *Open with...* (and remember to check *Always use this app to open .sh files*) to associate the sh files with this batch file.

**EDIT:** included `--login` argument for bash.exe to set all the appropriate linux specific environment variables (such as `$PATH`)

Comment: +1 because the solution does not need a compiler or to mess with the register (directly), but uses well known technologies.

Comment: This doesn't behave exactly the same as running the script after launching WSL since the PATH isn't set by bashrc. To get the right PATH change the last line to `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -ic "/mnt/%drive%/%relpath%"`.

Comment: I think you would still need to use the registry if you wanted to skip the manual _Open with_ dialog.

Comment: To set the $PATH (and other WSL environment variables) correctly, you just need to use `bash.exe --login [script]` instead of just `bash.exe [script]".

And the .cmd file can be assigned as default program if you Right-click a .sh file -> Properties -> General tab -> Type Of File -> Change, then click Browse and find the .cmd

I'm gonna edit the answer to include that!

Comment: When starting that batch from a 32bit application, bash.exe is not found. Explanation & Workaround: https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1105#issuecomment-248821689

Comment: I personally had to add a `pause` at the end to help me debug an issue.

Comment: I added `cd "%~d1%~p1"` in the second last line to run the script in it's directory.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent Vbscript method (for PSSGCSim's C# code) would be:

```
If WScript.arguments.count <> 0 And LCase(Right(WScript.Arguments(0), 3)) = ".sh" Then
    Dim WshShell: Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    strSHfile = WScript.Arguments(0)
    MyArr = Split(strSHfile, ":")
    strSHfile = "/mnt/" & LCase(MyArr(0)) & MyArr(1)
    strSHfile = Replace(strSHfile,"\","/")
    WshShell.Run "%systemroot%\system32\bash.exe " & """" & sSHfile  & """",,True
    Set WshShell = Nothing
End If
```

And the file association REG file is here:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.sh]
@="shfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\shfile]
@="SH Script File"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\shfile\shell\open\command]
@="wscript.exe \"D:\\Scripts\\bash.vbs\" \"%1\""
```

To make it run .SH files from network, you need to alter the script.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine with MinGW (I personally prefer one bundled with a SmartGit):

```
    ftype bashfile="C:\Program Files\SmartGit\git\bin\bash.exe" "%1" %*
    assoc .sh=bashfile
```

If running from the batch script '%' -> '%%':

```
    ftype bashfile="C:\Program Files\SmartGit\git\bin\bash.exe" "%%1" %%*
    assoc .sh=bashfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows 10 still didn't provide this feature (Nor drag-over to .sh) by default, I've decided to make a registry key that does just that;

You will be able to open an .sh file correctly after associating it to bash.exe; in addition, you can drag files to the .sh script to pass them as parameters.

You can download the key here:

http://www.mediafire.com/file/8lqd1v693uj1g6t/ShellBashScriptOpen_v7.rar

The key also enables the option to run the script in elevated mode (right click option - both windows admin and Linux superuser), while an extra (optional) key enables right click > edit with nano

Remember you have to have set bash.exe as default program to open .sh files to apply these changes (the executable path is C:/Windows/System32/bash.exe)

The main registry key executes the following script (being a reg key, remember \" becomes ", \$ becomes $, \\ becomes \ and %% becomes %):

```
#This makes bash.exe silently execute the command between quotes (whole code)
"%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\bash.exe" -c "

#Parses the dragged file paths from Windows paths to unix paths
path_param=\$(echo \"%*\" | sed 's/[[:space:]]\\([A-Z]:\\)/\\n\\1/g' | sed 's/[A-Z]:/\\/mnt\\/\\L&/g' | tr '\\\\' '\\/'\');
mapfile -t path_param <<< \"\$path_param\";
path_param=(\"\${path_param[@]//:}\");

#Same, but with the .sh script path
path_exec=\$(echo \"%l\" | sed 's/[[:space:]]\\([A-Z]:\\)/\\n\\1/g' | sed 's/[A-Z]:/\\/mnt\\/\\L&/g' | tr '\\\\' '\\/'\');
path_exec=\"\${path_exec//:}\";

#Removes the wole path (leaving only the file name) if the parameters are in the same directory of the script
if [[ \"\${path_param%%\\/*}\" -ef \"\${path_exec%%\\/*}\" ]];
    then path_param=(\"\${path_param[@]/#\${path_param%%\\/*}\\/}\");
fi;

#Sets working directory to the folder where the script is located
cd \"\${path_exec%%\\/*}\";

#Executes script with or without parameters
if [[ \$path_param == \"\" ]];
    then \"\$path_exec\";
    else \"\$path_exec\" \"\${path_param[@]/#\${path_exec%%\\/*}\\/}\";
fi;

#Leaves WSL console open after the .sh script finishes executing
cd ~; bash; "
```

ORIGINAL POST: [Can I drag and drop files to an .sh script using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows or Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1264874/can-i-drag-and-drop-files-to-an-sh-script-using-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-or-wi)

Comment: Please post the *answer* here, not just a link.  (I realize that the link in this answer points to another [SU] question — but the answer there is also a link-only answer.)

Comment: @Scott I edited the answer (used the original post's answer with some changed) and added a link to the original post in the bottom

Comment: This is still a link-only answer!

Comment: @Scott Edited after I got it back up (it was deleted by another moderator, along with the original post answer [which is still deleted]). Is the answer OK now or should I still make some changes? Also what about the other post?

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: @DavidPostill♦ the problem here is that they are two different questions (this one [which I just answered recently] being about opening sh scripts, the other being about enabling file drag and drop to sh script [which I created and self answered]); the registry script does both, so it can answer both questions. I originally just linked the other post, but I was told not to (but maybe that was just because also the other answer was a link-only answer, which should not be anymore)

Comment: @AlexSim In that case you should tailor the answer to fit each question.

Comment: I've made some small edits to both answers... Can I have my upvotes back now, pwease :3

Comment: @AlexSim Voting is anonymous.  If users think your answer is helpful they will issue an upvote.  However, I agree with David, your answer has made your question you asked a duplicate of this question.